# cast to array from a string with bracket

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
console.log(number);
[
  "1,2,3"
]
```

above is a string, how to cast it to array correctly? I tried `JSON.parse(number)` and  JSON.parse("[" + number + "]"); I still can't separate them and turn it into a proper array.

Comment: `number[0].split(',')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's **really** as you've shown, it's an array with a single entry in it, which is a string.

There's no "casting" in JavaScript because JavaScript is loosely-typed, but you can *convert* that single string into an array of strings via `split`:

```
number = number[0].split(',');
```

The `[0]` is there because what you've shown is an array, so we're using the only entry in it (at index 0).

**Live Example**:

```js
var number = ["1,2,3"];
number = number[0].split(',');
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(number));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

If it's really just a string, not an array containing a string, leave off the `[0]`:

```
number = number.split(',');
```

**Live Example**:

```js
var number = "1,2,3";
number = number.split(',');
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(number));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

If you want **numbers** in the array (`1`, `2`, and `3`) instead of strings  (`"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"`), we have to parse those. One way to do that is with `Array#map` and the unary `+` operator, which will convert its operand to a number if possible (or to `NaN` if not):

```
number = number[0].split(',').map(function(str) {
    return +str;
});
```

(Again, remove the `[0]` if what you're starting with is just a string, not an array containing a string.)

**Live Example**:

```js
var number = ["1,2,3"];
number = number[0].split(',').map(function(str) {
  return +str;
});

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(number));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: the last example using map(), why is there +str, what does that mean?

Comment: @AliceXu: *"...the unary `+` operator, which will convert its operand to a number if possible (or to NaN if not)..."* `map` calls the callback with each entry in the array, and builds a new array out of what the callback returns each time. The entry it passes in is the first argument to the callback, which I've called `str`. Returning `+str` converts the string to a number (`"1"` => `1`).

Comment: What if my string is like this str = "["1,2,3"]" ??

Comment: @AliceXu: Do you mean `'["1,2,3"]'`? E.g., a string with square brackets and numbers in it? In that case, you can either use `substring` to remove the brackets or `JSON.parse` to parse it into an array containing a single string, and then apply my examples above using `[0]`.